# Mac: Eclipse error import MySQLdb works fine on command line

Tags: python, mysql, eclipse, macos

I have been trying to install Mysql and Python along with MySQLdb module on MAC. I have been able to do that successfully. From the command line when i do import MySQLdb it works fine. However, I configured my Eclipse to point to my Python27 intepreter and when I try import MySQLdb from Eclipse, I get the architecture mismatch error. Here is the exact error

```
ImportError:
dlopen(/Users/bhaskaar/.python-eggs/MySQL_python-1.2.3-py2.7-macosx-10.7-intel.egg-tmp/_mysql.so,2): no suitable image found.
Did find: /Users/bhaskaar/.python-eggs/MySQL_python-1.2.3-py2.7-macosx-10.7-intel.egg-tmp/_mysql.so: mach-o, but wrong architecture
```

In the External Library tab under Pythonpath I point to

```
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/MySQL_python-1.2.4c1-py2.7-macosx-10.7-x86_64.egg/_mysql.so
```

Here is some more info

```
$ file $(which python)
/usr/local/bin/python: Mach-O 64-bit executable x86_64
$ file $(which mysql)
/usr/local/bin/mysql: Mach-O 64-bit executable x86_64
```

could you please help how I can resolve this issue. To me it seems like Eclipse is building everything as a 32 bit rather than 64 bit, but I am not sure. Thanks

Comment: if you do "`nm -arch x86_64 /Users/bhaskaar/.python-eggs/MySQL_python-1.2.3-py2.7-macosx-10.7-intel.egg-tmp/_mysql.so`", do you get a "`does not contain architecture`" response?

Comment: Hi Michael, you are right I do get the "does not contain acrchitecture response"  What does that mean and how do I fix the problem?